# How can I show the exact chapter page number in jasper index?

Tags: jasper-reports

I was looking for a solution about a problem on I'm thinking about it since few days. I try to explain it in the easier way. I have a master report where I collect a lot of details. Each detail contains a paragraph consisting in a paragraph title and a sub report that it can linked to more than one report (because I could scan more nested list). In main report I have a detail that contains an index. The index is composed by text labels. Near each text label,let's call it A, I would put the page number linked to each paragraph. I understood that this number should be represented by a variable that should be tide to a variable, in a subreport, that store the paragraph page number. Let's say that I can try it out in the report page that contains the second chapter. Inside the second chapter report page if I use the default variable $V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}, with evaluation time master, I can read the right number page, let's say number 5. Now the problem is take this number and send back to A(it doesn't matter how many sub report I have between the chapter page and the the master page). I read some documentation and I understood that to do it I should declare in master page the A variable, click on the band that store it and go to return values and tide A with the name of  each chapter  $V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}. How can I do it? I tried to do different test, for example to declare a new variable in each chapter page, let's say B, and link B to $V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}, and after link A to B. In this case in the master page I got every time null (I tried to change all evaluation time possible but I don't understand how to do it so far).

In the first case works just in the chapter page but I don't know how to send back to master page this value:

```
  <textField evaluationTime="Master">
  <reportElement x="170" y="0" width="240" height="30" uuid="0bc4318d-5b1b-4add-bcc7-422bc299096a"/>
 <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}]]> </textFieldExpression>
     </textField>
```

In the second case I declare in the chapter page and I try to tide it to variable A but also in chapter page the current page appears null. In chapter page:

```
<parameter name="custom_page" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: Its hard to immagine all that you want to achive, does it boil down to send back a value from subreport to main report? Have a look at this also http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/tableofcontents/index.html

Comment: Hi Alex K, ty for the reply. Should be quite simple, I don't want to use the table of content. I miss just this thing to finish the index. I don't know why I can get from subreport to master page the PAGE_NUMBER value but when I try to get the MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE I get always null.Any ideas? Ty

Comment: You have tried to use return parameter from subreport?, if it does not work can you please show a [mcve] (also with empty datasource) so we can test it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I try to make an example easier than the previous one. I Have a masterPage with 3 details. In the first detail my index, in the second the first chapter with a subreport and in the third the second chapter with a subreport. If I put a variable called subreport1_page_number inside the 2° detail, where chapter 1 is, I can print the correct corrent page number, let's say 3 (I can do it setting evaluation time = band). Now I put a new variable, called main_page_number,in the first detail next to the chapter 1 text label to show 3. I don't know how to set evaluation time, function, reset type and so on. I tried to set some values but I get null or other values not correct. I show you the master page. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.5.1.final utlizzo versione della libreria JasperReports6.5.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="multitable" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" uuid="1c6dc1c9-67af-43d5-bf1e-9243557c8048">
    <parameter name="firstSubreport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="secondSubreport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <variable name="subreport1_page_number" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="main_page_number" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$V{subreport1_page_number}]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="104">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="351" height="90" uuid="befbbb8d-e0c1-48a2-b552-30c8bfa2e1ea"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15" uuid="940a502b-f566-4d58-8627-bbedc63f8738"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[ Index]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
                    <reportElement x="70" y="46" width="172" height="15" uuid="4a5ebf00-2f22-429a-a83e-7a67f7a52f41"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isUnderline="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Second Chapter"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
                    <reportElement x="70" y="30" width="172" height="15" uuid="d6e6eba8-6a6a-44d5-9313-b206ad4c975b"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isUnderline="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["First Chapter"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="240" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="95d41927-54a7-4189-8067-84d5dce489a2"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{main_page_number}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
        <band height="131">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="4" y="5" width="220" height="18" uuid="42eed16d-33c0-47a3-b8ed-14a4069805ce"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["First Chapter"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="130" width="99" height="1" uuid="e79da7f1-796b-4e1a-87e4-a4ffb3789c84"/>
            </break>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="520" height="50" uuid="85501fc3-72c6-4679-9f1e-043d09a31567"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("firstSubreport")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{firstSubreport}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField evaluationTime="Band">
                <reportElement x="260" y="1" width="100" height="30" uuid="8a6ae7b1-7243-4bae-8e96-4a53cc6de69a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{subreport1_page_number}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="131">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{praticaRatingPrecedenteAttivi}==true]]></printWhenExpression>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="38" width="510" height="40" uuid="95fc7b61-3783-4c4c-9e8b-c717b02a279f"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("secondSubreport")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{secondSubreport}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="4" y="5" width="220" height="18" uuid="9a7428b8-7854-4d52-a304-0d271b7e4f22"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Second Chapter"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="130" width="99" height="1" uuid="5941ea3b-dea8-466a-92cd-4fa02a1600cc"/>
            </break>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```